# Java Program is not consistent?

Tags: java, arrays

I am getting a 3 digit value from database in 0 or 1 format like 001, 100, 111. Based upon the value I have to perform some operation I have written the code for but it is not consistent. It is working as expected for 3 values which I then add to `ArrayList`. However, it will not work when I pass less than 3 or more than 3 values to `ArrayList`

Below is the program which I have created please help me to rectify this program.

```
package com.company;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // write your code here

        String num;

        ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
        al.add("100");
        al.add("111");
        al.add("010");

        //al.add("111");
        String[] array;
        if (al.size() > 0) {

            for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {
                array = al.get(i).split("");
                System.out.println("Size of array is" + array.length);
                for (int j = 0; j < al.size(); j++) {
                    System.out.println("size at position" + j + " is " + array[j]);

                    if (array[j].equals("1") && j == 0) {

                        System.out.println("PODS Enalbe");
                    } else if (array[j].equals("1") && j == 1) {
                        System.out.println("BAM Enalbe");
                    } else if (array[j].equals("1") && j == 2) {
                        System.out.println("PNDE Enalbe");
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("No value found in PTM_TRIGGER Table");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "it will not work" .. can you be more specific on that?

Comment: You are only ever checking 3 indices. It will skip everything after that because you haven't told it what to do in those cases.

Comment: Suppose in the arraylist sometimes 1 value also be there and i can get 1000 value also the value will be always in 3 digit 0 and 1 format only. 
for each index of ArrayList i have to split the value and i am storing the value in array, I am iterating the array from 0 index and checking if index 0 having "1" value then print "PODS Enable" if secound index is one then print PNDE and if 3rd index is one then print BAM.

Comment: use a Debugger to see what is going on

Comment: Maybe it would help if you show us some data for which your code is failing.

Comment: please specify the operation you want to do with these number..

Comment: Suppose in the arraylist sometimes 1 value also be there and i can get 1000 value also the value will be always in 3 digit 0 and 1 format only. for each index of ArrayList i have to split the value and i am storing the value in array, I am iterating the array from 0 index and checking if index 0 having "1" value then print "PODS Enable" if secound index is one then print PNDE and if 3rd index is one then print BAM. –

Comment: your code won't even compile, so what is the code you are actually running?

Comment: given details information. @BhartiLadumor

Comment: Also, check the result of split. Your arrays are like [,1,0,0], not [1,0,0] so your code is never returning the correct result anyway

Comment: suppose i add 1000  to array list, then according to you what would be output?

Comment: Your `j` loop needs to stop at `array.length`, not `al.size()` which is for the outer loop. But you are overcomplicating things, just use `charAt` to get the individual characters in the Strings. And what happens when someone adds `1000` to the list is up to you to decide.

Comment: @BhartiLadumor that's besides the point. he's not talking about the variables in the arraylist, but about the number of variables in the arraylist. TiiJ7 and I found the same bug in his code, he's iterating until the wrong value, once that is fixed, his code works (almost) as it should

Comment: i know @Stultuske but only wanted to know that he want to check for all 1's in "111" or only for 1st 1

Answer (score 0):

In your inner loop, you need to check for `array.length()`, not `al.size()`.
I've changed your code a bit to make it more readable (and functioning)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        boolean isPODSEnable;

        // write your code here
        ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
        al.add("100");
        al.add("111");
        al.add("010");

        String[] array;
        if (al.size() > 0) {

            for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {
                array = al.get(i).split("");
                System.out.println("Size of array is" + array.length);
                for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
                    System.out.println("size at position" + j + " is " + array[j]);
                    if ( "1".equals(array[j])) {
                      switch(j) {
                        case 1: // not 0. Your array is [,1,0,0], not [1,0,0]
                              System.out.println("PODS Enalbe");
                              break;
                        case 2: System.out.println("BAM Enalbe");
                                break;
                        case 3: System.out.println("PNDE Enalbe");
                                break;
                    }
                }
            }
         }

        } else {
            System.out.println("No value found in PTM_TRIGGER Table");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is not the exact output which i am expecting below is the expected program.

Comment: 'below' is nothing. what do you mean by this?

Comment: okey, I get it. But the question you asked was: "why does it not run if I have any other number of elements than three", which is answered here. You were quite vague of the actual job description. You can indeed change the code to make it function the way you need it to

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments, the stop condition for your inner loop is wrong. But I feel that your approach is also a bit over complicated. You don't really need to split up the `String` to a `String[]`, you can directly access the characters with `charAt`. I also recommend using an enhanced for loop when looping a `List`, then you cannot make the mistake of using the wrong stop condition.

This will produce something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
    al.add("100");
    al.add("111");
    al.add("010");
    al.add("1000");

    if (al.size() > 0) {
        for(String s : al) {
            if(s.length() != 3) {
                System.out.println("String has invalid length");
                continue;
            }
            if(s.charAt(0) == '1') {
                System.out.println("PODS Enable");
            }
            if(s.charAt(1) == '1') {
                System.out.println("BAM Enable");
            }
            if(s.charAt(2) == '1') {
                System.out.println("PNDE Enable");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("No value found in PTM_TRIGGER Table");
    }
}
```

And what happens for Strings that don't have the correct length is up to you. In my program above it just ignores them.

Answer (score -1):

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TestClass {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    boolean isPODSEnable = false;

    // write your code here
    ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
    al.add("100");
    al.add("111");
    al.add("010");
    al.add("0110");
    al.add("000");

    if (al.size() > 0) {

        for (String s : al) {
            int index = s.indexOf("1");
            switch (index) {
            case 0: // not 0. Your array is [,1,0,0], not [1,0,0]
                System.out.println("PODS Enalbe");
                break;
            case 1:
                System.out.println("BAM Enalbe");
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("PNDE Enalbe");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Not Found");
                break;
            }
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("No value found in PTM_TRIGGER Table");

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Hi Guys, Thanks for your help below is the expected code change. you can find this program http://www.javatechworld.com/split-integer-value-in-java/